# Getting a schema does not exist error when referencing a table alias

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, amazon-redshift

When I try to run this below query joining two tables, I get the error:
schema "u" does not exist.

Where am I going wrong?

````
SELECT
       u.delivery_station_code AS dim_location,
       u.cycle_name AS dim_cycle_name,
      u.scac AS dim_scac,
       DATE(u.event_datetime) AS period_date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT u.scannable_id) AS Volume,
       v.mechanical_capacity AS mech_cap
FROM perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_onroad_events as u
left join perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_big_push_metrics as v
on
u.event_datetime=v.execution_date
and u.delivery_station_code= v.station_code
and u.cycle_name=v.cycle
WHERE DATE(u.event_datetime) between '2022-01-26' and '2022-02-03'
  AND ((shipment_type = 'Delivery' or shipment_pickup_instructions is NULL)) AND
      u.is_latest_by_shipment_status_and_eventdate = 'Y'
  AND u.shipment_status = 'PICKED_UP'
  AND dim_cycle_name in ('CYCLE_1', 'CYCLE_2', 'CYCLE_0')
  AND  (u.delivery_station_code like 'D%' or u.delivery_station_code like 'Z%')
  AND  u.scac ='AMAUS'
GROUP BY u.delivery_station_code, u.cycle_name, u.scac, u.DATE(u.event_datetime)```
````

Comment: I don't know Amazon redshift but this: `u.DATE(u.event_datetime)` looks suspicious. is `DATE` a function? if so, is it not a reserved word, and if not does it belong to schema u?

Comment: Please publish the error message in full.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your default schema

```
ALTER USER [YOURDOMAIN\USERNAME] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```